# Why .submit() is not being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my login form code. But the form submit and JSON response retrieval isn't happening at all. Where am I going wrong?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js">
        </script>
        <div id="login-box">
            <form id="login" method="post" class="login" action="http://localhost:3000/login/">
                <fieldset class="textbox">
                    <label class="username"> <span>Username or email</span>
                        <input id="username" name="username" value=""
                        type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username">
                    </label>
                    <label class="password"> <span>Password</span>
                        <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password"
                        placeholder="Password">
                    </label>
                    <button class="submit button" type="button">Sign in</button>
                    <p>
                        <a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <button id='theButton'>What?</button>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('.login').submit(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        type: $(this).attr('method'),
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was this handy **How to Format** box to the right of it, and a preview area underneath it. I'd expect someone with a >2k rep to know how to format things readably.

Comment: why id in title .. when you are using class to both form and in jquery submit

Comment: It's not being called because there is nothing that calls it. To submit a form you need to have a submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button type from "button" to "submit"

Comment: @Puck and don't mix classess and ids, please